# How to get the last modified date of an mysql table

Tags: mysql

I would ask how to get the last modified date of an mysql table? For the last modified date of an mysql table, I mean the last time that the table is changed,for example,due to table insert, delete,update,truncate, etc.

Comment: It's easy if you have a timestamp column that gets updated when the record is created or updated. Deletion of a record and truncation of the records in the table cannot be recorded this way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can read in mysql documentation for [The INFORMATION_SCHEMA TABLES Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tables-table.html),
you can get the update_time (and other information) with a simple query:

```
SELECT update_time 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_name = 'table_name';
```

Comment: Which version of mysql are you using? 
I read that there was a bug for innoDb tables [https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=14374]
They should have fixed it in MySQL 5.7.2

Comment: Hi @lyisia, I did a query, but the UPDATE_TIME is null..It only works for MyISAM, but not InnoDB

Answer (score 3):

It gives you the last modified one.

```
SELECT UPDATE_TIME 
FROM   information_schema.tables WHERE  
TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_dbname'   AND TABLE_NAME = 'your_tablename'
```

Comment: Hi @Anands23, I did a query, but the UPDATE_TIME is null..It only works for MyISAM, but not InnoDB

Comment: what is your mysql version ?

Comment: 5.7.16-log when I did a query `select version();`

Comment: check this out : http://serverfault.com/questions/622972/update-time-and-create-time-of-tables-is-showing-null-in-mysql                                                                                                                https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=14374             https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69689